# Unexplainable SQL msg using Bulk Insert on large data sets - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, crud

Below is the SQL code utilized to perform an insertion.

```sql
use Acs_DataStocks
BULK
INSERT [dbo].[AcsBy520072011Pus]
FROM 'D:\temp\ACS\ss11pusd_fixed.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
KEEPNULLS
)
GO
```

Errors reported in SQL Server Management Studio are:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 32 The bulk load failed. The column
>   is too long in the data file for row 3649556, column 156. Verify that
>   the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>  Msg
>   7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 32 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked
>   server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any
>   information about the error. 
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 32
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

Below is row number 3649556 from the offending data set:

> 2010000576537,P,01,02004,55,1039407,00021,56,1,1,,,2,,,000000,,,11,2,3,1,5,,,,,,,,,,,,3,5,3,3,3,000000,00000,00,000000,1,,11,000000,2,00000,00000,020400,40,1,1,,2,142,032,,,,1,01,,,,,,4,1,,0,4,000020400,000020400,055,228,02000,055,1,1,01,69,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,,,,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00022,00007,00037,00037,00022,00021,00024,00006,00024,00037,00020,00035,00039,00007,00021,00007,00024,00022,00006,00021,00021,00006,00036,00038,00020,00020,00023,00005,00022,00037,00021,00035,00036,00006,00020,00006,00022,00021,00006,00021,00021,00006,00038,00034,00022,00022,00021,00006,00024,00039,00020,00035,00037,00007,00020,00007,00021,00023,00006,00022,00022,00006,00036,00039,00021,00022,00020,00006,00019,00036,00025,00038,00038,00007,00020,00006,00021,00023,00006,00021,N.A.,N.A.////,N.A.,N.A.//,3500,292061,8170,6216

The value for the data field shown is "00024" .  The table was created with only varchar(50) fields. This error is reproducible, but not explained.  Why is this?

Comment: How many fields are there? Looks like 226 comma's in that string.

Comment: If you copy row number 3649556 into a separate file by itself will it import?